# How do sensations differ from each other?

Tags: neuroscience

The sensation of tough material and soft material is not the same but in both senses, sensory cells are the same. How do these two sensations differ from each other? Does this information carried like binary coding or is there special coding between neurons?

Comment: What makes you think the sensory cells are the same?

Comment: I did not mean all sensory cells are the same. I mean, in my example, sensory cells that sense the material is the touch receptors isn't it.

Comment: Touch receptors are quite diverse, but I suppose that's a start to an answer.

Comment: Welcome. This question is really broad; have you done any prior research? Please share that research, because as of now your answer can be tackled by various angles and is too broad to answer. Further, the post is wide open for discussion at this point. Any answer will likely be followed up by you with *'yes, but....'*. A great way to focus a question is by showing your efforts so far and letting us know exactly where in the process you get stuck.

Comment: Some related questions that may get you on your way: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/how-do-we-localize-pain?rq=1 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/how-does-the-brain-project-pain-on-to-a-particular-part-of-the-body?rq=1

Comment: Feel free to edit the question based on the comments above and it may be reopened